# Activate jquery function after "splash screen"

Tags: jquery, navigation, concept

I am working at a school project for a site with a simple navigation. So i am using keyup functions for scrolling.

[Demo model is on my webpage](http://pluijlaardesign.nl/school/)

The concept is quite simple, a screen pops up. You type in your name. "Log in" screen fades out and intro text comes in. (for all the non dutch people it says "Hi $name, welcome, lets start, as you can see there are some butons press one to navigate")

Only thing is, i only have de D key activated for testing, fortunately my name is Mike, so no D involved. But if your name is Dave (for example) if you press the D in the "Log in" screen, the page allready scrolls to the navigation point.

```
$(document).keyup(function(d) {
if(d.keyCode==68){
    $('body').animate({
        scrollLeft: $('#left').offset().left

    }, 'slow');
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

This is my jquery for the keystrokes (Only the D is currently activated, so more to follow, i know)

**Finaly the question:** How can I "deactivate" the keystroke function so that after the login screen fades out the keystroke function activates, and so u can use the navigation safely.

Tiny question 2: i have a form for your name

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="get"><input id="naam" type="text" name="Naam" /> <input id="sender" type="button" name="button" value="gaan!"  />  </form>
```

In combination with

```
$("#sender").click(function(){ 
$("#login").fadeOut('slow');
$("#callback").delay(900).animate(
{
    left:'40%',
    opacity:'1'
}, 'slow' );`
```

Now i know that a .submit function is possible, but in some weird manner, it doenst work in my page. how do i fix that?

Comment: not exactly sure what you try to do, but look at `.on`,`.off` and Namespaced Events of jquery, with that you have more control over adding and removing of event callbacks.

Comment: look at the demo link, there is the prototype,,